# Injecting forward ref of ancestor through children to grand-child

Tags: angular, angular5

#### The Problem

Right now I am using some components to obfuscate some of the more complex functionality away from the implementing devs allowing them to write blocks of code more easily.

The stack of components looks like this from the code side:

```
<smart-nav-tile-group>
    <radio-checkbox-group>
        <smart-nav-tile>
            <radio-checkbox-wrapper>
```

What I am trying to accomplish is to inject a forward reference of the `radio-checkbox-group` component into each of the `radio-checkbox-wrapper` components so that there is two-way communication between the two components.

So in my `radio-checkbox-wrapper` I have the following in my `constructor` function:

```
@Inject(forwardRef(() => RadioCheckboxGroupComponent)) public inputGroup: RadioCheckboxGroupComponent
```

This works all well and fine as long as the `RadioCheckboxGroup` component is the direct parent of `RadioCheckboxWrapper`.  However with the `SmartNavTile` component in the middle, it throws the following error:

```
SmartNavTileComponent.html:2 ERROR Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[RadioCheckboxWrapperComponent -> RadioCheckboxGroupComponent]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[RadioCheckboxWrapperComponent -> RadioCheckboxGroupComponent]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for RadioCheckboxGroupComponent!
```

#### The Question

How can I create a forward reference to the `RadioCheckboxGroup` component in the `RadioCheckboxWrapper` component regardless of how far up the ancestor tree it has to go to find it?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer for this?

Comment: @EliezerBerlin I have marked the correct answer. The best way to do this is with a service that tracks the elements you need access to. In this manner it acts as a data store for all of your elements and their current states that can be accessed by any component, similar to an NGRX data store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Communicating child to parent by reference is not a good design. I would suggest to have some kind of services which can help to communicate between parent and child.

### Unrelated Components: Sharing Data with a Service

When passing data between components that lack a direct connection, such as siblings, grandchildren, etc, you should you a shared service.

> Use case : If we create a function in any one of these components that changes the value of the message. when this function is executed the new data it’s automatically broadcast to all other components.

### data.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

  private messageSource = new BehaviorSubject('default message');
  currentMessage = this.messageSource.asObservable();

  constructor() { }

  changeMessage(message: string) {
    this.messageSource.next(message)
  }

}
```

### parent.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from "../data.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  template: `
    {{message}}
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./sibling.component.css']
})
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {

  message:string;

  constructor(private data: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.data.currentMessage.subscribe(message => this.message = message)
  }

}
```

### sibling.component.ts

It can be sibling or child component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from "../data.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sibling',
  template: `
    {{message}}
    <button (click)="newMessage()">New Message</button>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./sibling.component.css']
})
export class SiblingComponent implements OnInit {

  message:string;

  constructor(private data: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.data.currentMessage.subscribe(message => this.message = message)
  }

  newMessage() {
    this.data.changeMessage("Hello from Sibling")
  }

}
```

Comment: Updated the answer for your reference

Comment: I tried this and provided the service at the `CheckboxRadioGroup` level, however for some reason instead of creating two singletons for each group they are somehow being provided all into one singleton.  Any idea why this would be happening?

Comment: It will create the singleton to the level it was provided through. If you are providing the services in each component then it will create separate instance for all and they will not able to communicate. So to start with, I would recommend you to provide at Module level and see if you are able to communicate.

Comment: I WANT them to be separate, but the service is acting like a global service and all of the inputs are going into the one service instead of having one for each group.

Comment: Then you should provide in CheckboxRadioGroup Module where you should have other required control declared otherwise if you just provide the at CheckboxRadioGroup then other control like Checkbox or Radio will not be able to communicate.

Comment: I have it provided in CheckboxRadioGroup, and it is still acting global.

Comment: No, it should not. Put the console in the constructor of service and check how many times it is printing.

Comment: It logs out once, so it is definitely only creating one instance of the service.

Comment: How many RadioCheckboxGroup you have in html after rendering ?

Comment: there are definitely two in my markup once it is rendered.

Comment: By adding the provider to the `RadioCheckboxGroup` component I have it now creating the service once for each group, however when I inject the service into the `RadioCheckboxWrapper` component it somehow creates one global singleton of the service. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve using ViewChild(), and you can access any component thats added in the template.

```
<smart-nav-tile-group>
    <radio-checkbox-group>
        <smart-nav-tile>
            <radio-checkbox-wrapper>
```

In radio-checkbox-group Component, you can access Radio Checkbox Component using

```
@ViewChild(RadioCheckboxRrapperComponent)
  radiocheckboxwrapper: RadioCheckboxRrapperComponent;
```

Comment: Neither `@ViewChildren` or `@ContentChildren` return any of the RadioCheckboxWrapperComponent instances.

Comment: r u accessing inside AfterViewInit method?

Comment: Yes, and I even added a 2 second timeout to try to wait for them to be available.

Comment: This is the exact opposite of what OP asked for. OP wants to access `RadioCheckboxGroup` from `RadioCheckboxWrapper`.